# In-App Purchase For Google Pay With Flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, google-pay

So am trying to use google pay in my flutter application and below is my code. When I run the application is shows google pay dialog with my google pay email and card details and an error "Unrecognised app. Please make sure that you trust this app before proceeding. When I press the "Continue" button I get "Request failed" "Unexpected developer error, please try again later" Please what am I doing wrong?

````
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_pay/google_pay.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';
  String _googlePayToken = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }



  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await GooglePay.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    await GooglePay.initializeGooglePay("my google play base64EncodedPublicKey");

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Running on: $_platformVersion\n'),
                Text('Google pay token: $_googlePayToken\n'),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Google Pay Button"),
                  onPressed: onButtonPressed,
                )
              ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onButtonPressed() async{
    setState((){_googlePayToken = "Fetching";});
    try {
      await GooglePay.openGooglePaySetup(
          price: "10.0",
          onGooglePaySuccess: onSuccess,
          onGooglePayFailure: onFailure,
          onGooglePayCanceled: onCancelled);
      setState((){_googlePayToken = "Done Fetching";});
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      setState((){_googlePayToken = "Failed Fetching";});
    }

  }

  void onSuccess(String token){
    setState((){_googlePayToken = token;});
  }

  void onFailure(){
    setState((){_googlePayToken = "Failure";});
  }

  void onCancelled(){
    setState((){_googlePayToken = "Cancelled";});
  }
} ```

When I run the application is shows google pay dialog with my google pay email and card details and an error "Unrecognised app. Please make sure that you trust this app before proceeding. When I press the "Continue" button I get "Request failed" "Unexpected developer error, please try again later" Please what am I doing wrong?
````

Comment: I'm not familiar with Flutter or the google_pay package that you are using, but the unrecognised app message typically gets displayed when you are using the `TEST` environment. This message typically goes away when your Google Pay merchant account has been submitted and approved for production and your app targets the `PRODUCTION` environment.

Comment: will payment still go through? Cause from my end the payment failed.

Comment: Google Pay doesn't process the payment. It returns a token that you can use to process a payment with your payment service provider. If you don't send it to your payment provider service provider then it won't be processed. Additionally, in `TEST` Google Pay doesn't return real payment credentials so you can't actually execute a real payment with a `TEST` payment token.

Comment: But this time am not using the TEST.

Comment: Google Pay doesn't process the payment in production either. You need to pass the payment token to your payment provider for processing if you want to process the payment. Did you pass the payment token to your payment provider?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?